# Gaussian process regression from predictions

Tags: probability-distributions, spline, gaussian-elimination, confidence-interval

Can any body provide example of a gaussian process regression being used to generate confidence intervals?

Comment: If you have Matlab and the statistcs toolbox you can use the GP toolbox to generate examples and they have inbuilt ones I believe. The confidence intervals are part of any GP prediction since they are just the standard deviations at each point (or 2 st-devs normally) which are obtained from the diagonal in the posterior covariance matrix.